# ¿Crear un ejecutable de varios archivos?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

"""Resulta que uso pyinstaller para crear un ejecutable pero tengo varios scripts en pyqt5 como ventanas y al crear el instalador de la pantalla principal me falla el programa ¿sera porque debo crear el ejecutable de todos los archivos ?¿si es así como lo hago?

mainwindow.pyw

ventanaAnalisis.pyw

ventanaPostAnalisis.pyw

Evidentemente empieza en la primera pantalla y dependiendo de cosas va pasando por otras. todos los tutoriales que vi indican como convertir en ejecutable un único archivo a exe para la aplicación pero ninguno me dice como hacer que estos tres se conviertan en un único ejecutable.
Supongo que abra una solución mas elegante que copiar y pegar todo el código en un único archivo"""

Comment: provee un [mre]

Comment: ¿Podrías ayudarme?, soy principiante en esto y hay varias cosas que desconozco,
El ejecutable que deseo lograr está conformado por tres archivos .py y un png, escribí todo el código con anaconda y lo probé en esa misma consola, después para hacerlo un .exe instale los paquetes de pyinstaller, sin embargo desconozco como lograr el exe, intente crear un exe del .py principal y como creí no funciono, luego intente crear un exe incluyendo los tres .py, de nuevo no funciono, si me puedes ayudar te lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: @IsraelHuh Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera medalla. La zona de respuestas no es la adecuada para realizar preguntas. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, utiliza el enlace [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), haciendo referencia a esta si consideras que puede estar relacionada.

Answer (score 0):

Bien sea un archivo o varios pyinstaller crea un ejecutable con todos ellos el fallo en mi caso era un archivo.txt que habia creado para pruebas en el cual el programa funcionaba a la perfeccion y que cuando cree el eejecutable no estaba donde debía por lo tanto daba un error(ojo los errores en los exe no aparecen simpleente se rompen) habiendo colocado un try except se soluciono.
Me disculpo por la pregunta ya que habiendo encontrado el problema pues fue una estupidez de principiante.